# MPC State Space MIMO Scalling

Tags: state, space

I am trying to simulate statespace model of "citation aircraft" by Example 2.7 page 64,Book,"Predictive Control with Constraints,Jan Maciejowski,2002". `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` are state space matricises of model.

I have just one input and three outputs. Input scales in radian. First output scales in radian. Second output scales in meter. Third output scales in meter/second.

But in plot of book scales change to input scales change to degree. first output scales change to degree. and rest of outputs remaianed as before.

My question:
Is it need to change `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` to new scale?
For example due to changing input scale from radian to degree is it need to change `B` matrix to new `scale(degree)` before using it?
`B = rad2deg(B)`? Or for first output I change `C` matrix to `C(1,:) = rad2deg(C(1,:))`?

Comment: Questions that ask for a specific problem from a textbook that probably none of us have access to will most likely not get answered.  Perhaps you should include the question here, as well as what you have tried.  Also, what programming language / environment are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Its general question maybe happen for every body,but i face with that in that text.Im using matlab. my problem is that need any scalling?